# @EntityGraph/JOIN FETCH are not working with Bytecode Enanhcement

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I'm using bytecode enanhcement to lazily load the avatar attribute of User entity throught Basic annotation; I also want lazy loading on the identity card related to a Member entity (that extends User).
Till now everything is working fine, my code is the following:

User class:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    private String surname;

    @Lob
    @NotNull
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private byte[] avatar;

}
```

Member class:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "members")
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Member extends User {

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    private IdentityCard identityCard;

}
```

IdentityCard class:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "identityCards")
public class IdentityCard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @NotNull
    private byte[] backImage;

    @Lob
    @NotNull
    private byte[] frontImage;

}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

application.yml:

```
...
spring:
     jpa:
          open-in-view: false
...
```

Now, in my controller I'd like to fetch both the avatar and the identity card of a member throught EntityGraph annotation in the repository

Controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("members")
public class MemberController {

    @Autowired
    MemberService memberService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String get(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        Optional<Member> member = memberService.findFullMemberById(Long.valueOf(id));

        // Using model to pass member and let thymeleaf process it
        return "members/form";
    }

}
```

MemberRepository:

```java
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Long> {

    ...

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"avatar", "identityCard"})
    Optional<Member> findFullMemberById(Long id);

}
```

But the Member object I get always has both avatar and identityCard attributes setted to `null`.
I've also tried with Query annotation and LEFT JOIN FETCH with the same result.

```java
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Long> {

    ...

    @Query("select m from Member m LEFT JOIN FETCH m.identityCard identityCard where m.id=:id")
    Optional<Member> findFullMemberById(Long id);

}
```

- Spring Boot: 2.2.5.FINAL
- Hibernate: 5.4.12.FINAL

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 distinct problems, as of Hibernate 5.4.26.

### 1. Lazy basic attribute

You're trying to eagerly fetch a lazy basic attribute with `@EntityGraph`, which is not supported in Hibernate 5, but there is a feature request for Hibernate 6 to allow EntityGraphs to control loading of basic entity state (not only associations): https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9270

I don't know if there is any workaround, and I think it can't exist. An alternative to `enableLazyInitialization` is to use **sub-entities** or even better, **projections**, as explained in https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate

### 2. ToOne association

Indeed, `enableLazyInitialization` allows lazy-loading `@OneToOne` with `@LazyToOne(NO_PROXY)`, but it becomes harder to JOIN FETCH: you have to initialize the association while the session is open to be able to use it outside the session, and it still produces a N+1 SELECT!

All lazy singular attributes are excluded from the initial load plan (including join columns of lazy `ToOne` associations).

**Without join fetch**

When finding a Member by id, Hibernate will generate:

1. a first SELECT to get the eager attributes: `id,name,surname`
2. when needed, a N+1 SELECT to read the lazy attributes of the corresponding implicit `@LazyGroup`: `avatar,identity_card_id`
3. a N+1 SELECT to fetch the associated `identityCard`

**With join fetch**

When joining and fetching the identityCard, Hibernate generates the proper SQL JOIN to fetch the associated identityCard, but it misses the `member.identity_card_id` join column, resulting with a LazyInitializationException (I don't have a null, as mentioned in your question, but it's quite the same).

1. a first SELECT to get the eager attributes `id,name,surname` and the joined entity attributes: `identityCard.id,identityCard.frontImage,identityCard.backImage`
2. when needed, a N+1 SELECT to read the lazy attributes of the corresponding implicit `@LazyGroup`: `avatar,identity_card_id` *(same as without the join fetch!)*

There are open issues related to this bug (or feature...):

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13203 Fetchs used into criteria query seems to be ignored when bytecode enhancement is enabled.
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13134 JOIN FETCH does not work properly with enhanced entities

  #### 2.1. The fix

Enable this new option:

```
hibernate.bytecode.allow_enhancement_as_proxy=true
```

You'll get the same behavior as if bytecode enhancement and enableLazyInitialization were not enabled, and JOIN FETCH will work as expected, but you'll still be able to lazily load basic attributes and `@OneToOne`.

This way, you don't even need to add `@LazyToOne(NO_PROXY)` (except for `@OneToOne`) and `@LazyGroup` on all lazy `ToOne`.

See my comment on the issue.
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13134?focusedCommentId=107604

For more information about this new feature, check
https://in.relation.to/2019/07/30/bytecode-proxy/

---

**Another advice**

When not using the new `hibernate.bytecode.allow_enhancement_as_proxy` nor `@LazyGroup`, all lazy attributes are implicitly part of the same group. Thus when lazily loading `identityCard`, Hibernate will also load the `avatar`, which is probably not what you want.

So you should separate the lob and the identity card with `@LazyGroup("lob")` and `@LazyGroup("identityCard")` or use `hibernate.bytecode.allow_enhancement_as_proxy`.